# Arduino uno disconnected after a few minutes

Tags: c#, arduino, windows-7, serial-port, arduino-uno

I created a WPF app to open 2 relay boards, I'am using a Arduino Uno 
as an intermediary, the WPF app connect to Arduino through Serial Port and send commands to open the relays. The problem is that in one of the arduinos board, after a few minutes of use, it disconnects. The app throws an exception with this message `The device is not connected`.

I do not found any solution.

Here my arduino code:

```
int delayVal = 100;
char action = "n";
void setup() {
  // put your setup code here, to run once:
  pinMode(8,OUTPUT);
  pinMode(7,OUTPUT);
  Serial.begin(9600);
  delay(100);
  digitalWrite(8,HIGH);
  digitalWrite(7,HIGH);
}
void loop() {
  // put your main code here, to run repeatedly:
  if(Serial.available() > 0){
      action = Serial.read();
      newAction();
  }
}
void newAction(){
  if(action == 'o'){
     openRelays();
  }else if(action == 'c'){
    closeRelays();
  }else if(action == 'd'){
    bool canContinue = false;
    while(!canContinue){
      if(Serial.available() > 0){
        String val = Serial.readString();
        delayVal = val.toInt();
        canContinue = true;
      }
    }
  }else{
    Serial.println("No hay nada");
  }
}
void openRelays(){
  digitalWrite(8,LOW);
  digitalWrite(7,LOW);
}
void closeRelays(){
  digitalWrite(8,HIGH);
  delay(delayVal);
  digitalWrite(7,HIGH);
}
```

Comment: ..."The problem is that in one of the arduinos board, after a few minutes of use, it disconnects..." Always the same board disconnecting? Are both boards set up identically and have the same function?

Comment: Always the same board, I have a 3 computers each one with its arduino, only one is disconnected for now. After a week of use this started to happen.

Comment: Genuine board or cheap clone?

Comment: It is not Genuine but the integrated circuit is an ATMEL.

Comment: sounds like a defective board. If you have a replacement board use it--and monitor the situation. I certainly does not sound like a software issue.